# Append /src to an Optional path

Tags: java, optional

My method `getProjectDir()` will return an Optional which contains the path to the project directory, or an empty container:

```
Optional<Path> getProjectDir() { ... }
```

I have another method, `getSrcDir()` which depends on `getProjectDir()`:

```
Optional<Path> getSrcDir() {
    Optional<Path> projectDir = getProjectDir();
    if (projectDir.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.of(projectDir.get().resolve("src"));
    }

    return Optional.empty();        
}
```

Everything works, but I feel the if statement is clunky. Is there any single statement which says "If the project dir exists, append "/src" to it, else return an empty optional. Please let me know if and how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is! You're looking for [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

```
Optional<Path> getSrcDir() {
    return getProjectDir().map(p -> p.resolve("src"));
}
```

Comment: This is as beautiful as it should be.